# WSO2 API Manager methods are not loaded from WSDL

Tags: soap, wso2, wsdl

I'm trying to proxy an SOAP EPR using API Manager. 
I follow the procedure of creation of REST API "I have a SOAP End Point" and I provide the WSDL. but in the "design" tab i can't see the methods. Seems like API Manager "does not understand" the WSDL I provided. 
I can browse The same WSDL  and I used SOAPUI client, the WSDL is correct and I can see the methods and test them. 
Does anyone exerienced this kind of issues with API Manager? 
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Before APIM 2.2.0 you will see only a single resource.

Enhanced support for exposing SOAP services as REST APIs by auto-generating the REST interface by parsing the WSDL of the SOAP Service was introduced in APIM 2.2.0.